# How to use <lightning:select> on Community? PURE Markup, no APEX, no JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightningselect, lightning-namespace

On a standard page in a Napili-based Community a want to render a `<lightning:select>`. As a starter, I just want to have one simple empty option.

The html-way it works just fine:

```
<select value="" >
    <option text="" value="" label="-" />
</select>
```

But doing the very same with `<lightning:select>` fails

```
<lightning:select aura:id="myPicklist">
    <option text="" value="" label="-" />
</lightning:select>
```

I get only this error and the entire page does not render anymore. The page output collapses to this

> Invalid Page

In the browser console, I found this as WARNING:

> aura_proddebug.js:24582 WARNING: An internal server error has occurred
>   Error ID: 1403404160-155558 (-1306587905) in aura_proddebug.js:24582

Why this is happening? Is `<lightning:select>` not usable in Communities at all? Where this is documented? I've checked the docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm but could not find any reason why it shouldn't work.

Why we get only this error Id and nothing readable? In the console, why this is only a WARNING and not a ERROR?

Do I have to prepare myself and expect other member of the lightning namespace failing in a similar manner?

**Full Source-Code**

Just toggle the commented lines to see the issue:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    TEST
    <select value="" >
        <option text="" value="" label="-" />
    </select>
    <!--<lightning:select aura:id="elfSelectProducts" class="elfPicklist elfSelectProducts">-->
    <!--    <option text="" value="" label="-" />-->
    <!--</lightning:select>-->
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not specifying the required attributes in your component as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm):

> Attribute Name ----- Attribute Type --------- Required?
>
> label -------------- String  ----------------------- Yes
>
> name  -------------- String   -----------------------     Yes

```
<lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Select an item">
    ...options...
    </lightning:select>
```

Comment: Yup. this got me more times than I can count. Seems simply throwing `"Missing required attribute: Name"` would have been much more useful

Comment: Error ID: 1403404160-155558 (-1306587905) is much more intuitive imo

Comment: In my best Sheldon voice **"Sarcasm?"**

Comment: :joy:  hehe, you got me there =P

Comment: @Eric FYI, Winter 18 is supposed to be a lot more intuitive error-wise, but we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Gents - great, it works! But... why the heck it works without these required attributes in LEX flawlessly? Only in the community it fades out with that nice error. +1 on sarcasm and counter-intuition. Stuff like this a graveyard of developer-hours buried already. Hope @sfdcfox is right on W18

Comment: Two other things I noticed: a) the attributs just need to exist and can be empty (name="" label=""). b) In Community-mode the label is rendered while in LEX it's not. This inconsistency doesn't make any senses either IMHO. LCs in LEX and Community should behave as similar as possible.

Comment: @UweHeim - Sadly this will not be the last or only inconsistency you will find between LEX, Community, ltng:out etc. There are time sinks all over the place and workarounds galore. It will get better though

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @glls answer, even if you use [variant="label-hidden"] you must still specify [label=""] as it is one of the required attributes and yes, the < label > tag will still render in the HTML just with nothing inside of it.  That was a fun one to track down.